# Code breaking characters in XML with PyTest

Tags: xml, jenkins, junit, pycharm, pytest

I am using PyCharm and I am seeing these weird special characters in PyTest JUnit output.

When this code runs on Jenkins these characters seem to be breaking Jenkins' Junit Parser.

Here's what I see as the text:

```
<error message="failed on setup with &quot;Exception: [1;31mjob finished with exception : list index out of range[0m&quot;"
```

Here's what I see on PyCharm:

[image]

The JUnit parsing plugin on Jenkins fails with this error:

```java
09:56:52 ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
09:56:52 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 872; columnNumber: 72186; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the value of attribute "message" and element is "error".
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1473)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:981)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:447)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:250)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
09:56:52    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
09:56:52    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:445)
09:56:52 Caused: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 872 of document  : An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the value of attribute "message" and element is "error".
09:56:52    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:462)
09:56:52    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:325)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:178)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:378)
09:56:52 Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to read /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_runner@10/junit
09:56:52 Is this really a JUnit report file? Your configuration must be matching too many files
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:386)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:308)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:224)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:196)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.<init>(TestResult.java:151)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:144)
09:56:52    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
09:56:52    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:107)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:149)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parseAndSummarize(JUnitResultArchiver.java:243)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:166)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
09:56:52    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1905)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
09:56:52    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
```

Is there any way to clean up this XML to avoid the parser from failing?

Answer (score 0):

This python script seems to be fixing the problem:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', xml_string).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```